# Post complex nested object from AngularJS to C# WebAPI Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, api

I want to post an JavaScript object from AngularJS to C# Api
The simple type is posted but not object et Array of object

```
var event = {
                        dateDebut: dateDebut,
                        heureDebut: heureDebut,
                        heureFin: heureFin,
                        invites: invites,// Array Of Object 
                        titreRdv: titreRdv,
                        userEmail: EmailGoogle
                    }

$http.post(CreateRdvPath, event)
                    .success(function (data) {
                       // Success code
                    })
                    .error(function (data) {
                       // Error code
                    });
```

My C# Controller function

```
[HttpPost]
        public string createRdv(CalendarEvent MyEvent)
        {

        }
```

CalendarEvent

```
public class CalendarEvent
    {
        private string dateDebut, heureDebut, heureFin, titreRdv;
        private string userEmail;
        private List<Utilisateur> invites;

    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting in console? or on server side?

Comment: NullPointerException when i want acces to "Invites" Array object

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a default constructor for any class that contains other objects.
In your case, add this constructor that initializes the object.

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public CalendarEvent()
    {
        invites = new List<Utilsateur>();
    }

    private string dateDebut, heureDebut, heureFin, titreRdv;
    private string userEmail;
    private List<Utilisateur> invites;
}
```

This should then allow the framework to correctly parse the object.

Comment: "you are one guly motherf**er* " Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$http.post` should pass data as `{MyEvent: event}` with server side action parameter name

**Code**

```
$http.post(CreateRdvPath, {MyEvent: event})
.success(function(data) {
  // Success code
})
.error(function(data) {
  // Error code
});
```

**OR**

```
$http.post(CreateRdvPath, JSON.stringify({MyEvent: event}))
.success(function(data) {
  // Success code
})
.error(function(data) {
  // Error code
});
```

Comment: @Amadou why CalendarEvent properties are private

Comment: it's private but a have getters et setters methods in my class.